# Should I check if an image file exists or have a hasImage column in the DB?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database-design

I display a lot of items, each can have a picture, when it hasn't I want to show 'nopicture.jpeg'

Should I check for each item if its jpeg (id.jpeg - i save them as id of the item + .jpeg) exists on the hard drive or have a bit column in the database for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are good that going to the disk for each image will be more expensive than getting the results for all images on a page from the database, though with the advent of very fast SSDs this may not be the case.

You will need to test, of course, but I would go with a database column at first.

Comment: Files on disk are much more prone to accidental deletes or filename changes meaning that the DB won't reflect (unless updated every amount of time) those and you might receive that a file exists (based on DB lookup) when it actually doesn't. Given the advances in hardware I'm much more in favor of failsafe solution than worrying about performance.

Comment: @mare - It depends on how you restrict access to the files and how the application has been written.

Answer (score 1):

Though it might be bad practice, why don't you make that part of your query?

```
SELECT ISNULL( Picture, "nopicture.jpg" ) as ItemPicture From MyTable
```

Once in a while, you could run a script that validates each image path in your table and removes in invalid paths.

Answer (score 1):

Checking for it on the hard drive will be slower. I wouldn't necessarily use an actual column in the db either. Check for it in the db and return a column based on whether there is a picture or not like this:

`CASE WHEN column_with_picture IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS has_picture_TF`